# Where is WinHttpClients in HttpClient?

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm following a example of HttpClient4.4, which is 
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/httpclient-win/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/win/ClientWinAuth.java

However, this class cannot be compiled, because of NOT FOUND WinHttpClients.
I'm sure that the lib I imported is 4.4. So, is there anyone knows what's going on? (I have already checked my classpath. Still not found this class also.)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows specific is shipped as a separate module. Make sure to add `httpclient-win` as a dependency to your project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient-win</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Wonder why a separate module has been made, which has also cost my time finding the `WinHttpClients` class in a `httpclient.jar` file

Comment: @ZhaoGang, it makes sense to split out modules that are not needed by everyone (it is more natural for the codebase to be like that anyway).  It is especially important when a module has dependencies that don't make sense on your platform.  Notice `httpclient-win` depends on `net.java.dev.jna.*` modules.  Another user might not want all that.  It takes up precious space on your embedded server.  Or it is unneeded bloat that might increase security 'attack surface'.